# why is my Gps location not being updated?

Tags: android, service, gps, alarm

I am trying to record the gps signal of a user every 30 mins. I am using alarms and the service is being called, however it seems that when this function is called by the alarm it does not seem to update the gps location, it uses a previous value.

Here is my code to update my location, note that in the  bottom I have another alarm set for the same function so that it will be called again.

```
package com.cellphone;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import com.cellphone.astralweb.R;

public class UpdateLocation extends IntentService {
    public static final String id = "";

    public UpdateLocation() {
        super("UpdateLocation");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", 0);
        final String id = prefs.getString("ID", "");
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        // 30seconds and it stops
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(
                "http://iphone-radar.com/gps/gps_locations");

        JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();

        try {
            holder.put("id", id);
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

            LocationListener loc_listener = new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };
            String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                    false);
            try {
                Looper.prepare();

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                        loc_listener);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Location location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "hh:mmaa MM-dd-yyyy");
            holder.put("time", sdf.format(c.getTime()));
            holder.put("time_since_epoch",
                    System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            try {
                holder.put("lat", location.getLatitude());
                holder.put("lon", location.getLongitude());
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                try {
                    holder.put("lat", -1.0);
                    holder.put("lon", -1.0);
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
            httpost.setEntity(se);
            httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String response = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
            org.json.JSONObject obj;
            obj = new org.json.JSONObject(response);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssaa");
            try {
                History.addHistory(sdf2.format(c.getTime()), "GPS",
                        "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + "\n"
                                + "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                History.addHistory(sdf2.format(c.getTime()), "GPS",
                        "Latitude: " + -1.0 + "\n" + "Longitude: " + -1.0);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            Intent setAlarm = new Intent(UpdateLocation.this,
                    UpdateLocation.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                    UpdateLocation.this, 0, setAlarm, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            int UPDATE_TIME = prefs.getInt("Update_time", 30);
            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, UPDATE_TIME);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        }
    }
```

Here is the function I placed inside a button called update location. This function works as its supposed to and properly updates the location. The code is the same so I was wondering why its not updating in the service.

```
public class updateloc extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if (response != null) {
            // check if this does anything later

        }
        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ImTracking.this, "",
                "Updating Data...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", 0);
        final String id = prefs.getString("ID", "");
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        // 30seconds and it stops
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(
                "http://iphone-radar.com/gps/gps_locations");

        JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();

        try {
            holder.put("id", id);
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

            LocationListener loc_listener = new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };
            String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                    false);
            try {
                Looper.prepare();

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                        loc_listener);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Location location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "hh:mmaa MM-dd-yyyy");
            holder.put("time", sdf.format(c.getTime()));
            holder.put("time_since_epoch",
                    System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            try {
                holder.put("lat", location.getLatitude());
                holder.put("lon", location.getLongitude());
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                try {
                    holder.put("lat", -1.0);
                    holder.put("lon", -1.0);
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
            httpost.setEntity(se);
            httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String response = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
            org.json.JSONObject obj;
            obj = new org.json.JSONObject(response);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssaa");
            try {
                History.addHistory(sdf2.format(c.getTime()), "GPS",
                        "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + "\n"
                                + "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                History.addHistory(sdf2.format(c.getTime()), "GPS",
                        "Latitude: " + -1.0 + "\n" + "Longitude: " + -1.0);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        progressDialog.dismiss();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think reason why your AsyncTask is only sending the last location is because your not really using the LocationListener interface correctly, or actually at all.

I think you need to put some code in the the onLocationChanged method to do something with the location, like probably put it into a member var of your activity so you can do stuff with it.

The reason why the UI is updating via button is really just the side effect of having a registered a listener (that doesnt actually so anything when it hears a new location) which causes the LocationManger to go ahead and update the lastKnownLocation, which your button them gets the value from. So the deaf listener is causing LocationManager to poll for updates, and update it's own lastKnown, which you click handler is relying on.

The reason this doesnt work in the AsyncTask is that a Task runs once and then dies. So when you register yet another listener it will never have a chance to get an event because it's parent (the task) is going to run all the way through to the end of doInBackground and then die. So, it's dying before it ever gets a location changed event...which inside your task actually wouldnt have done anything anyway (no body to the onLocationChanged method).

I think you need to step back from this prototype code and rethink your design a bit.

Using the AsyncTask to handle the http post is a good idea but having it and the Activity itself be a listener is not going to work. Especially without implementing something useful in the onLocationChanged event.

Consider having your Activity be the listener and have a member var for Location. In your onLocationChanged event, clone the location you get from the event to your memeber var, and then you could first update your UI with the new location and then start your task to send the location to your web site.

You can continue to have the Task declared as `Task<Void,Void,Void>` and just access the member var of your activity from the task, or more properly, pass it to one declared as `Task<Location,Void,Void>`.

Also, I think youre going to need to consider checking to see if a task is currently already running before starting new one as with the registerForLocationUpdates(provider, 0,0) youre going to get them much faster than your web site is likely to be able to take them in, especially with a 30s timeout on the connection.

You could simply test to see if the task is currently running before starting a new one, or use a boolean member var in the activity which gets set true in onPreExecute and false in onPostExecute, then just check that before starting a new task.

Even that might be to chatty with the web site. You might want to create a data structure to hold many locations and then, once you've accumulated some quantity of them, send them all in one batch to the web site.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand what you mean by the location listener isn't doing anything. My "updatelocation" button barely lasts a second so I was sure that my location would be inaccurate. What I have is basically a cut and paste of what I've found on the website. The website only takes one point, so its up to me to send a good one. Do you think you could help me write a gps listener that takes data in the background and then sends an accurate point when the update location service is called? Thanks

Comment: So, you only need to send one location reading to the web site, but you want it to be accurate to within a certain number of meters before you send it?

Comment: exactly, and a problem I currently have is that after a certain amount of time (while running in the background maybe around 2 hours) the update location service does not update the location and just uses the last location that is recorded. I call my service with an alarm (see the end of the service class, it re-calls itself every 30 mins)

Comment: Ok, I'm not totally familiar with use of Alarm but it seems straight forward. I think what you need to do is extend your HandleIntent method to grab the location in the onLocationChanged handler there, check to see if it's accurate enough, fire the task and then set you next notify. If it's not accurate enough, either set up another alarm or sleep and loop until you get the next location. It's a little unusual to offer to write code for someone on SO but I'm willing to help. Goto http://www.sense8.mobi/about.aspx and follow the contact link to contact me for details.